# How can I ignore type in a Firebase security rule

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-security

The Firebase security rules do strict equality checks but I'd like to be able to check and ignore type where $userID may be a string or number. i.e. $userID = 1 or $userID = '1' and auth.id is a string.

```
".write": "$userID == auth.id"
```

I tried .toString() but it doesn't appear to be supported.

```
 ".write": "$userID.toString() == auth.id"
```

Is this possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you absolutely have to convert you could add an empty string, but you normally shouldn't need to:

```
".write": "$userID + '' == auth.id"
```